# Как найти min/max типы (по размеру) в шаблоне c произвольным количеством параметров?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Моя наивная рекурсивная реализация этих функций, но в таком виде это конечно не работает. Работают только первые две проверки. `

```
template <typename U, typename V>
using smaller_type = std::conditional_t < sizeof(U) < sizeof(V), U, V > ;

template <typename U, typename V>
using larger_type = std::conditional_t < sizeof(V) < sizeof(U), U, V > ;

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct min {
    using type = T;
    type = smaller_type<type, Ts>...;
};

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct max {
    using type = T;
    type = larger_type<type, Ts>...;
};

int main() {
    using min_t = min<int16_t, int32_t, int8_t, long long>;
    static_assert(is_same_v<int8_t, min_t>, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, на такую обобщенность, как в предыдущем ответе, я не претендую, может, даже ответ не совсем верный (не чувствую я эти вариадические шаблоны...), так что критикуйте:

```
template <typename T, typename MT>
auto min_type()
{
    return conditional_t < sizeof(T) < sizeof(MT), T, MT >{} ;
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename ...Ts>
auto min_type()
{
    return min_type<T,decltype(min_type<U,V,Ts...>())>();
};

template <typename ...T>
using min_t = decltype(min_type<T...>());

int main()
{
    cout << is_same_v<int8_t,min_t<int16_t, int32_t, int8_t, long long>>  << endl;
    cout << is_same_v<int16_t,min_t<int16_t, int32_t, int8_t, long long>> << endl;
}
```

Да, защиту от дурака (менее чем 2 типа) я не ставил, но это уж совсем просто...

Answer (score 1):

Наивная рекурсивная реализация выглядит примерно так:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template
<
    template
    <
        typename xx_Left
    ,   typename xx_Right
    >
    typename x_Predicate
,   typename... x_Types
>
class
t_SelectImpl;

template
<
    template
    <
        typename xx_Left
    ,   typename xx_Right
    >
    typename x_Predicate
,   typename x_First
,   typename... x_Rest
>
class
t_SelectImpl<x_Predicate, x_First, x_Rest...> final
{
    public: using
    t_Type = typename x_Predicate<x_First, typename t_SelectImpl<x_Predicate, x_Rest...>::t_Type>::t_Type;
};

template
<
    template
    <
        typename xx_Left
    ,   typename xx_Right
    >
    typename x_Predicate
,   typename x_Left
,   typename x_Right
>
class
t_SelectImpl<x_Predicate, x_Left, x_Right> final
{
    public: using
    t_Type = typename x_Predicate<x_Left, x_Right>::t_Type;
};

template
<
    template
    <
        typename xx_Left
    ,   typename xx_Right
    >
    typename x_Predicate
,   typename... x_Types
>
using
t_Select = typename t_SelectImpl<x_Predicate, x_Types...>::t_Type;

template
<
    typename x_Left
,   typename x_Right
>
class
t_MinPredicate final
{
    public: using
    t_Type = ::std::conditional_t<(sizeof(x_Left) < sizeof(x_Right)), x_Left, x_Right>;
};

static_assert(::std::is_same_v<::std::int8_t, t_Select<t_MinPredicate, ::std::int16_t, ::std::int32_t, ::std::int8_t, long long>>);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/81WsvvoKn

Answer (score 1):

Кроме всего прочего хотел понять как разворачивается вариативный пак именно в случае структур, без использования шаблонных функций. Спасибо всем кто ответил. Теперь я во всеоружии.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
using smaller_type = std::conditional_t < sizeof(A) < sizeof(B), A, B > ;

template <typename A, typename B>
using larger_type = std::conditional_t < sizeof(A) < sizeof(B), B, A > ;

template <typename ...>
struct smaller_element_type;

template <typename T>
struct smaller_element_type<T> { using type = T; };

template <typename A, typename B, typename ...Rests>
struct smaller_element_type<A, B, Rests...> {
    using type = smaller_type<A, typename smaller_element_type<B, Rests...>::type>;
};

template <typename ...> struct larger_element_type;

template <typename T>
struct larger_element_type<T> { using type = T; };

template <typename A, typename B, typename ...Rests>
struct larger_element_type<A, B, Rests...> {
    using type = larger_type<A, typename larger_element_type<B, Rests...>::type>;
};

int main() {

    using min_t = smaller_element_type<int16_t, int32_t, int8_t, long long>::type;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_same_v<min_t, int8_t> << std::endl;

    using max_t = larger_element_type<int16_t, int32_t, int8_t, long long>::type;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_same_v<max_t, long long> << std::endl;
}
```